# serialize ruby fixnum by denominator into an array

Tags: ruby, math

I have a number, say it's 1000000. I want to give a second number, say 100 and create an Array that looks like [0,100,200,300,400....1000000]. I'm having trouble finding a way to iterate in a way that would serialize based on a given denominator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 200
i = 10

(0..n).step(i).to_a
  #=> [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120,
  #    130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
```

See [Range#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html#method-i-step).